# Search through listview

Tags: java, android, listview, search

It is quit complicated what i would like to achieve.
For now i have a listview displaying items, but

1. the listview is normally displayed at first and when i start typing in the edit text it filters the listview
2. Every letter i type changes the listview.

And what i would like to do is

1. The listview is empty at first.
2. The list view start being filtered only after i finish typing the whole word in the edit text.

Any help.

Here is my code for now:

```
etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String text = etSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                myAppAdapter.filter(text);
            }
        });
```

Filter:

```
public void filter(String charText) {
            charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            itemArrayList.clear();
            if (charText.length() == 0) {
                itemArrayList.addAll(arraylist);

            } else {
                for (ClassListItems st : arraylist) {
                    if (st.getProname().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText) || st.getData().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                        itemArrayList.add(st);
                    }

                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: Can't You just load the whole ListView when the user press enter on keyboard? Don't filter it every time text changed

Comment: @iknow I think that is going to take alot of time because the listview will contain maybe like.
10 billion item.
that is why i need to filter them.

Comment: But I think there isn't a better way. If You do it like I said You ll just load list view once when user complete writing